# TravisCI cache Python PIP

Tags: continuous-integration, pip, travis-ci

I am trying to cache PIP dependencies in my builds in order to make them faster but without success:

Here is how my build file looks:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
env:
  - DJANGO=1.6 RUN_AGAINST=development
services:
  - rabbitmq
  - memcached
branches:
  only:
    - master
cache:
  directories:
    - ~/virtualenv/python2.7/
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script:
  - cp myprojname/proj/settings/local.example.py myprojname/proj/settings/local.py
script:
  - python myprojname/manage.py test
  - behave -t ~wip myprojname/features
```

Notice this part:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - ~/virtualenv/python2.7/
```

I was hoping it would cache dependencies installed via PIP from requirements.txt file but every builds installs all dependencies from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching is Travis Pro only at the moment. If you happen to be a Travis Pro customer, then I believe your code should work.